# Programmatically map flutter emulator's device id and he emulator id

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, adb

I have defined a bunch of emulator profiles. Each has a different emulator id which can be checked with `~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -list-avds`

Any emulator can be started with `~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd EMULATOR_ID`. At start time it gets assigned a device id. The first one is usually `emulator-5554`. That device id is needed later, for example when starting an app on the device.

The problem arises when more than one emulator is started in parallel. At this point `adb devices` just returns a list of device ids without indication of which emulator belongs to which device id.

`flutter devices` gives more detail but as all emulators have the same signature it still doesn't help to identify them.

Question: I would like to programmatically start integration tests on different device emulators but for that, I need to know which device id represents a particular emulator. How can I do that?

To put it all together, here is a typical session. Notice how at the end I can't tell which device id belongs to the Pixel 2 emulator:

```
➜  ~/StudioProjects/ft (integration_test) ✗ adb devices                                                  
List of devices attached

➜  ~/StudioProjects/ft (integration_test) ✗ flutter devices                                             
2 connected devices:

macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64
Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 112.0.5615.137

➜  ~/StudioProjects/ft (integration_test) ✗ ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -list-avds          
Nexus_10_API_33
Nexus_7_API_33
Pixel_2_API_33
Pixel_6_API_33

➜  ~/StudioProjects/ft (integration_test) ✗ ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_10_API_33 & 
[1] 23358
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.10.0 (build_id 8807927) (CL:N/A)                                                                                                                
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath /Users/sylvia/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis/arm64-v8a/
[...]

➜  ~/StudioProjects/ft (integration_test) ✗ ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_7_API_33 & 
[2] 23579
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.10.0 (build_id 8807927) (CL:N/A)                                                                                                                
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath /Users/sylvia/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis/arm64-v8a/
[...]

➜  ~/StudioProjects/ft (integration_test) ✗ ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_33 & 
[3] 24138
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.10.0 (build_id 8807927) (CL:N/A)                                                                                                                
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath /Users/sylvia/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a/
[...]

➜  ~/StudioProjects/ft (integration_test) ✗ adb devices                                                   
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5556   device
emulator-5558   device

➜  ~/StudioProjects/ft (integration_test) ✗ flutter devices                                               
5 connected devices:

sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5556 • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5558 • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64
Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 112.0.5615.137
```

Comment: You can check the device properties of each emulator using e.g. `adb shell getprop`

Comment: That only works if there is a single emulator running, not if I have multiple which I want to keep apart.

Comment: You know that you can as command-line option specify the device adb should connect to when executing commands?

Comment: I know, but that's exactly my point. I need to specify the device via device id (emulator-5554), not via emulator id (Pixel_2_API_33). If I have started several emulators I have no way of telling which device id belongs to which emulator id.